# How can I browse non-snap software online?

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-center, synaptic

How can I browse non-snap software for Ubuntu 20.04 online?

[This nine-year-old thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88926/how-can-i-browse-the-ubuntu-software-centre-online) suggests apps.ubuntu.com, which redirects to snapcraft.io, which appears to contain only snaps. I'm trying to find a piece of software that will perform a particular function, but I am only interested in things I can install via Synaptic or apt.

Thanks.

Comment: I use CLI tools (`apt search` etc), but the online equivalent of that is https://packages.ubuntu.com/ but it's not a store; just a package database (just as Debian's is).

Comment: The normal way most folks browse is by using the Ubuntu Software application.

Comment: Ugh. I uninstalled the Ubuntu Software app because it depends on snap, which slows my computer to a standstill and then sets it on fire. So there is seriously nowhere one can browse Ubuntu software other than (a) the built-in app (which I can't use) and (b) CLI or equivalent (which only helps if you know exactly what you're looking for)? That's kind of a... defect... IMO.

Comment: You can use package management tools on your system (`synaptic`, `muon`, `aptitude` etc) but they're not online and not stores (they're package managers ; deal only with *deb* packages, and allow searches). You can use a browser to look up what's available - but it's not in one location; eg. use GNOME's web pages for GNOME apps; KDE pages for KDE apps etc... but each only offers details about it's own packages (the Ubuntu Software Store combines them into the one location on your machine but you don't want to use that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use package management tools on your system (`synaptic`, `muon`, `aptitude` etc) but they're not online and not stores (they're package managers ; deal only with *deb* packages, and allow searches).

You can use a browser to look up what's available - but it's not in one location; eg. use GNOME's web pages for GNOME apps; KDE pages for KDE apps etc... but each only offers details about it's own packages (*the Ubuntu Software Store combines them into the one location on your machine but you don't want to use tha*t).

- For GNOME apps, look at - https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps
- For KDE apps look at - https://apps.kde.org/
- For LXQt apps look at .... for MATE apps look at.. for Xfce etc...

ie. they're managed by the various Projects that create them, and not in a single managed store; that's done on your machine in the program you don't want to use.

Other stores exist too, Software Boutique, Discover etc. but some of those include *snap* and other packages too.

I use CLI tools (`apt search` etc), but the online equivalent of that is https://packages.ubuntu.com/ but it's not a store; just a package database. These deal with only the packages you specifically use (ie. `apt search` will search for *deb* packages, `snap search` looks for *snap* packages etc).

Comment: As Flatpak is not a Snap, you can also add https://flathub.org/home :)

Comment: Thank you, everyone. (FTR, I'd love to use the Ubuntu Software Store, but I couldn't figure out a way to uninstall snap without also uninstalling the software store. And snap is too processor-intensive for my use, so I'm stuck.)